# mpirun - Use each node's local env variables instead of master node's

Tags: bash, environment-variables, mpi, distributed, mpiexec

I am trying to run mpirun from the master node. If I do the following:

`mpirun -np 2 -hostfile /job/hostfile --map-by node --tag-output -bind-to none hostname`

The output looks good, **two different hosts**:

```
[1,1]<stdout>:azeuscc9800000I
[1,0]<stdout>:azeuscc9800001H
```

But when I run:

`mpirun -np 2 -hostfile /job/hostfile --map-by node --tag-output -bind-to none echo $HOSTNAME`

I get the **same host printed twice**:

```
[1,1]<stdout>:azeuscc9800001H
[1,0]<stdout>:azeuscc9800001H
```

It seems the $HOSTNAME variable (and probably other env variables) gets evaluated before mpirun sends the command to the remote node, which defeats the purpose. I have tried using the '-x' parameter unsuccessfully as well (same output, same master hosts printed):

```
mpirun -np 2 -hostfile /job/hostfile --map-by node --tag-output -bind-to none -x HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME echo $HOSTNAME
```

But from what I understand, this parameter is used to **export the master env variable** to the other nodes, whereas I want the **local env variable** assignment on each node to be used in the command for each node.

Does anyone know if I am using the mpirun command incorrectly, or if there is something else that needs to be done to achieve this functionality?

Comment: $HOSTNAME is evaluated by the shell in which you run mpirun. So you are really calling mpirun azeuscc9800001H

Comment: I can't tell what you're really trying to do. You could write a shell program that prints the hostname, and run that in parallel with mpirun. You could also try escaping the dollar.

Comment: the oneliner here is `mpirun ... bash -c 'echo $HOSTNAME'` (assuming your MPI implementation does not propagate `$HOSTNAME` from the head node).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Wow and thanks. I tried earlier except using the same thing (bash -c) with double-quotes and it didn't work. I have little to no experience with bash so hopefully will get better at this over time

Comment: you need to escape `$`, so with double quotes, you would `mpirun ... bash -c "echo \$HOSTNAME"`